# Android Dialog from different class

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity, static, dialog

I am building an android app and want to invoke a dialog from a non-activity class (that is happening in the background).
I would want the dialog to be shown on a particular activity but in order for other classes to invoke this function, it needs to be static but I cannot call `getSupportFragmentManager()` from a static context. 
Is there a work around this issue? this is the code I am trying to use.

```
    public static void method_invoked_returned_null(String response) {
        ErrorDialog errorDialog = new ErrorDialog();
        ErrorDialog.errorType = "Response Command Error";
        ErrorDialog.errorDialogMessage = "Error in Invoking " + response
                +  ". Do you want to continue?";
        errorDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Wrong Response Dialog");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two solutions to do

1:go with broadcast receiver and register the broadcast in onResume in your activity and unregister it in onPause.

2:you can add static field instance in your activity and set value in onResume and remove it in onPause

```
private static AppCompatActivity instance;
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    instance = this;
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    instance = null;
}
public static void method_invoked_returned_null(String response) {
    if (instance == null)
        return;
    instance.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            ErrorDialog errorDialog = new ErrorDialog();
            ErrorDialog.errorType = "Response Command Error";
            ErrorDialog.errorDialogMessage = "Error in Invoking " + response
                    +  ". Do you want to continue?";
            errorDialog.show(instance.getSupportFragmentManager(), "Wrong Response Dialog");
        }
    });
}
```